# Accessing properties in templates by their name

Tags: templates, groovy, gstring

given the following pieces of code:

groovy:

```
binding = [key1: "val1"]
def f = new File('test.template')
engine = new GStringTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(f).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

test.template:

```
<% keyName = "key1" %>
```

Is there a way to access val1 by keyName in test.template?

This:

```
${ binding[keyName] }
```

does not work (No such property: key1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding). Any ideas? Maybe the name of the map holding the properties is different?

I know I could just write:

```
${ key1 }
```

but I need to access property key1 using variable keyName.

Comment: I've read some Groovy code and found the way: use ${ delegate[keyName] }. Delegate is a private field of Closeure, so I think there should be more elegant solution to my problem. Still looking for an answer.

Comment: Seems like that is adding an extra level of indirection.  To start, think you would have to add keyName: 'key1' to your binding map, but I haven't been able to make the template work by doing that...

Comment: `delegate."$keyName"` or `delegate[ keyName ]` is the way forward

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is better but I got the following to work (somewhat)

```
Map binding = [ keyName: 'key1', key1: "val1", m: [key1:'val100', key2:'val2']]
def f = new File('test.template')
def engine = new groovy.text.GStringTemplateEngine()
def template = engine.createTemplate(f).make(binding)
println template.toString()
```

with the following template:

```
$keyName
$key1
<%= m[keyName] %>
```

But this relies on a submap that holds the values you are looking for.

I can see scenarios where in the binding, you pass a list of fields you want to process or display (rather than knowing them ahead of time), so you would have to get the field names from a well-known variable and then process the others possibly thru a submap.